# Why is this function neither surjective nor injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Reading answers for one of my homework, I found a statement:

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring, $a \in R$, and $F\colon R \to R$ is given by $F(b) = ab$. **If a is not a unit, then $F$ is not surjective. So as $R$ is finite, $F$ is not injective.**

How does the implication work here? I understand the definitions of injection and surjection but I find it difficult to apply them here. Why does the finiteness of a ring imply its injection? Hope some experts can help me.

Comment: Are you assuming $\;R\;$ is a unitary ring?

Comment: A function from a finite set to itself is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Comment: @JamieCarr That's what "unitary ring" means: a ring with a multiplicative unit/

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah obviously, thank you!

Comment: @DonAntonio XD!

Comment: @DonAntonio What's a unit if the ring has no identity?

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure what *you mean* by "identity" in the universe of ring theory, but if you use standard wording then ""the unit of a ring"" and "The identity of a ring" seem to be synonymous words for the same ring. What the OP would be meaning is beyond my knowledge and that's the reason I asked her/him. It wouldn't be the first time, or the second one, or...the 40th time...that a term is either misused or used with knowing its true meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\;f\;$ is surjective, then there is $\;b\in R\;$ s.t. $\;ab=1\;$ (assuming $\;R\;$ is unitary) , and thus $\;a\;$ is a unit...contradiction.

And now just observe that a function from any finite set fo itself is injective iff it is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am just bad at these logics.....